# Preventing closure compiler from renaming certain variables

Tags: javascript, compression, google-closure, google-closure-compiler

I have a javascript file with a global object that must not be renamed (`_gat` from the Google Analytics async tracker).

This object must not be renamed by the Google Closure Compiler as Google Analytics looks for a variable with this specific name.

I've looked into the Javascript Doc notations that are mentioned: http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler.html - However, I cannot find anything regarding the "protection" of a variable.

The problem exists no matter if I use simple or advanced compilation.

How can I ensure that the `_gat` variable is not renamed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) web app, you can set `js_externs`.  Refer to [Advanced Compilation and Externs](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html) for more examples.

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @output_file_name default.js
// @js_externs _gat
// ==/ClosureCompiler==
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the goog.exportSymbol function from base.js. Documentation is here: http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_base.js.html

Usage is like

```
goog.exportSymbol("_gat", _gat)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on that please? Where do I find further information?

Comment: (Sorry for the terse initial reply, was replying from my phone and my screen-keyboard-fu is weak).

Answer (score 3):

See http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2011/01/property-by-any-other-name-part-1.html the part about "All Unquoted"

putting certain vars inside ' ' >>> 'bob'  prevents them from being renamed by the compiler

Comment: This is an interesting option. Even when performing ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS, Closure will not rename string references to methods. Eg it will not rename window.foo if referenced like: window['foo']

Answer (score 2):

If it isn't declared as part of the code you are compiling than an extern declaration is appropriate:
http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html#externs